# Few Files missing/Not uploaded after Sharepoint upload of entire folder structure

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, microsoft-teams

We tried to migrate 5GB of files from SVN to Sharepoint which has many nested folder structures. To perform this we have downloaded files from SVN and used sharepoint web portal to upload as "Folder". I have selected the root folder where it has 5GB of files. It was processed for few hours and ended without any errors. Or I dont know where I am supposed to look for errors. After folder upload when I perform random validation, found that many folders are incomplete and did not find expected files in those folders.

I have searched in internet found that below tool is available for local sharepoint to Microsoft 365. Is there any other tool or the steps to upload local files to sharepoint.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/introducing-the-sharepoint-migration-tool

What we tried - We selected an entire root folder of 5 GB size which had many subfolders and files inside it to upload it to sharepoint through upload folder option.

Expected Result - All the subfolders and files inside the root folder should get uploaded on sharepoint

Actual Result - We found that some of the files and subfolders from the root folder did not get uploaded on sharepoint and the job had completed without any error being thrown or maybe I don't know where am I supposed to look for errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can try File shares to Migrate your on-premises file share content to Microsoft 365.

Go to **SharePoint admin center-->Migration-->File shares.**
[image: Find File shares]
For more information, please refer to:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/mm-get-started